# how to use third party javascript code in magento2 payment?

Tags: magento2

I am facing problem while adding third party javascript code in my payment module in magento2.

following is my code.

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
    'jquery',
    'Vendorname_Modulename/js/stsdk'
    'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator'
],
function (Component, $, STDirect) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendorname_Modulename/payment/module-form'
        },

        getCode: function() {
            return 'vendor_module';
        },

        isActive: function() {
            return true;
        },

        validate: function() {
            STDirect.setupSDK('23842', "testnumber", 'typeofenv');
            STDirect.card.createToken(number, exp_month, exp_year, ccv, function (result) {
                var secretkey = '';
                if(result.status==0){
                    secretkey = result.card.secretkey;
                }
                document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
                alert(secretkey);
            });
            var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
            return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
        }
    });
}
```

);

I have tried above code, stsdk.js is loaded in network but it gives me following error :

```
ReferenceError: STDirect is not defined
STDirect.setupSDK('23842', "testnumber", 'sandbox');
```

I have also checked by load this js file in header but same error appear.

My question is how to execute third party javascript code in define scope. 
I tried with the custom javascript function after define function but it is also not callable from validate function and when I use require[] function within define function it raise error.

I appreciate any help.